# How to handle a "subform" in a form using react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, yup

I have a form with multiple fields and one of those fields is asking for a promo code with a button next to the field. When the button is pressed, the value of the promo field should be validated before a call to the backend is made. I'm using `react-hook-form` to handle the values and validation using their `resolvers/yup` package.

```
const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    getValues, 
    formState: { errors },
} = useForm<CheckoutInputFields>({
    resolver: yupResolver(checkoutValidationSchema),
});

const onSubmitHandler = async (values: AddLeadInput) => {
    // Submit
    console.log(values);
};

const onSearchHandler = async () => {
    // Get value 
    const promo_code = getValues('promo_code'); 

    // TODO: How to validate the promo_code
    // TODO: If promo_code is invalid, add error to errors
}

return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmitHandler)}>
        <InputField
            label="labels.first_name"
            placeholder="placeholders.first_name"
            name="first_name"
            register={register}
            error={errors.first_name}
        />

        <InputField
            label="labels.last_name"
            placeholder="placeholders.last_name"
            name="last_name"
            register={register}
            error={errors.last_name}
        />

        {/* other fields */}

        <InputWithButton
            label="labels.promo_code"
            placeholder="placeholders.promo_code"
            name="promo_code"
            register={register}
            button_label="buttons.search"
            button_action={() => onSearchHandler()}
            error={errors.promo_code}
        />

        <Button type="submit" label="actions.submit" width="full" />
    </form>
);
```

It's not a problem to get the value of `promo_code` in the onSearchHandler but I don't know how to validate this field using a part of the `checkoutValidationSchema` and `yupResolver` so an error comes into the `formstate.errors` object of react-hook-form. If this is not possible what would be the best option? Create a separate schema and state specific for this field and error?